# Ppopulating tableview covers other ui elements

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I am facing a problem with my QTableView as it blocks off the other Ui elements after populating it with variables. This is my Intended Ui Design

[image]

What the tableview does after being filled up (with test variables)

[image]

Was there something which I missed out when setting up the ui in the Designer app? Sorry for the novice question as its my first time dealing with tableviews.

The code to populate the table:

```
    def createTable(self):
        # Create table
        header_labels = ['Username', 'Password', 'Account Type']
        profiles = [["test", "pokemon","nanana"], ["dreams", "nani","hikari"]]
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(profiles))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(header_labels))

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header_labels)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        for i,profile in enumerate(profiles):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(profile[0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(profile[1]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem(profile[2]))
        self.tableWidget.move(0, 0)
```

My Ui codes (If required for reference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>618</width>
    <height>463</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Arial</family>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Account Management</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="horizontalLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>301</width>
     <height>194</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <property name="sizeConstraint">
     <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QTableView" name="profileView">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
       <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="showGrid">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>430</x>
     <y>300</y>
     <width>158</width>
     <height>112</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="addProfileButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Add Profile</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="deleteProfileButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Delete Profile</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="updateProfileButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Update Profile</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Logout</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Show a [MRE] (the code that fills the table)

Comment: @eyllanesc hi, I have added the code to fills the table. hope that that is what you were saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against using fixed size. Such constraint is useful only in very specific scenarios (for example your application is supposed to be shown on displays with very specific dimensions and resolution such as embedded systems). In general you should let it resize properly and allow it to be rendered in a proper manner regardless of the resolution and screen size.

Your problem is the lack of layout for your widget:

[image]

You need to add it so that the top-level layout takes care of the resizing of your table view and buttons:

[image]

I also don't know why you have put your table view inside a layout all by itself. It doesn't make sense unless you plan to group it with other widgets like you have done with the set of buttons. A layout is useful only if you have more than one widgets inside. Otherwise you can just work with the resizing policy of your widget and throw the layout away.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working by adding all my ui elements into the layout file!

Comment: @QingHongTeo So my answer is the answer to your question? If so, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if QtDesigner didnt create a fixed width and height but using `.setFixedWidth()` and `.setFixedHeight()` worked.

Comment: See my answer. Your solution is not a recommended one and doesn't actually fix the problems with your UI form.